# React Native hairlineWidth not working on iPad using Animated.View

Tags: react-native, ipad

I am using `borderBottomWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth` to style a thin line in my react native app.

While starting layout adjustments for tablets, I noticed this line disappears on my iPad Air 2 device. Is this a bug, or am I using `StyleSheet.hairlineWidth` wrong?

Comment: are you using  it on a `View`?

Comment: Good point. An `Animated.View` to be exact.

Comment: give it a `borderWidth: Stylesheet.hairlineWidth`, see if it shows. or else, you can give it a `borderBottomWidth: 0.5` instead